# postgres фильтрация по битовой маске, по вхождению бит

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице example есть поле mask - битовая маска, содержит в себе сочетание параметров отображения. Как можно отфильтровать выборку по вхождению конкретного бита в Postgres?

Comment: Да как обычно... ``WHERE поле AND маска <> 0``